# Wordpress automatic news posting

Tags: wordpress

i am looking for a plugin that automatically searches on news websites for a keyword and makes a post for that news item. Where showing only 20 / 30 or something words and placing the source url under it. So not violating any copright laws and sending the visitors to the source url.

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own will require deep knowledge of PHP CURL functions, but there is already a plugin built for exactly this.

1. http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-automatic-plugin/1904470
2. There is also another one called wp robot

It can search different websites and even their feeds for your required keywords and then posts these articles on your website.